# Erro "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped" ao clicar no botão do aplicativo

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, button, onclick

Estou rodando meu aplicativo no Genymotion, desenvolvendo no Android Studio.

Toda vez que roda minha aplicação eu clico no botão para fazer o cadastro, mas ao clicar me deparo com a seguinte mensagem "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped", onde após a aplicação é finalizada.

Obs: Estou usando Firebase para cadastrar os dados

Código da minha `Activity`

```
    package com.example.matheus.MyApp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class CadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Button mCadastro;
    private EditText mEmail, mSenha;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user !=null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CadastroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        mCadastro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cadastrar);

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);

        mCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String senha = mSenha.getText().toString();


      //linha 56 AQUI          mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha).addOnCompleteListener(CadastroActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Cadastrado com sucesso! Efetue o login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
    }
}
```

Código onde detalha onde está o erro:

> 02-17 13:27:45.439 1961-1961/com.example.matheus.MyApp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.matheus.MyApp, PID: 1961
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.example.matheus.MyApp.CadastroActivity$2.onClick(CadastroActivity.java:56)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); qual o retorno dessa linha ? é retornado alguma instancia ou ta voltando nulo ?

Comment: Pra essa Activity volta nulo (assim entendo eu)..  Vai guardar os dados cadastrados no firebase e em outra Activity vai conferir a autenticação..

Comment: Poderia dizer quais as configurações do Sdk android do projeto, e qual versão do android vc esta testando?